# Assign key to values based on groups

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Values of array are grouped together if they have the same `$record->parent_id`. How can I assign to each group a key that starts from `0` and iterates for every member of a group and only for that specific group? Every consecutive new group starts from `0` again.

Example: if `$record->parent_id` is `2`, current iteration of `foreach` loop assigns a `0` to key. Next iteration has `$record->parent_id` of value `56`, its key is `0` again! Next iteration has `$record->parent_id` of value `2` again, hence its key is now `1` and so forth.

My current code:

```
<?php foreach ($records as $key => $record): ?>   

<tr id="<?php echo $key; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $record->parent_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $key; ?></td> //here I wish to get key starting from 0
    <td><?php echo $record->title; ?></td>
</tr>     

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I notice that your current code introduces an ambiguity, since it uses `$key` twice for different things.

If I correctly understand what's your need:

- `$key` in 1st and 2nd lines is some existing key you get from each record and which must become the `id` of the corresponding generated `<tr>`.
  To emphasize it I will change its name below to `$record_key`
- `$key` in ghe 4th line is a count number within the group of all records having the same parent_id.
  This can be achieved by merely counting rows in their relevant group.

Here is the result:

```
foreach ($records as $record_key => $record) {
  if (!isset($groups[$record->parent_id]) {
    $groups[$record->parent_id] = 0;
  }
?>   
<tr id="<?php echo $record_key; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $record->parent_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $groups[$record->parent_id]++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record->title; ?></td>
</tr>     
<?php
}
```